# JQuery function doesn't work on Chrome on Mac, but works on Chrome on Win 7 and all other browsers

Tags: jquery, macos, google-chrome

Reference this page:
http://www.ivault.sg/nproduct.php?pid=116&cat=2

Selecting an option on the dropdown box by the side should change the href of 'Add to Cart'.

However this does not happen specifically on Chrome on Macs, but works on all other browsers, even on Chrome in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the "click" event, use "change", as in

```
$("#productOptions").change(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("value");

    if (id != "") {
        $("#productAddToCart").attr("href","addtocart.php?code="+id);
    }
});
```