# Why does select box on mac chrome doesn't respond to click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery function doesn't work on Chrome on Mac, but works on Chrome on Win 7 and all other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295642/jquery-function-doesnt-work-on-chrome-on-mac-but-works-on-chrome-on-win-7-and)

I have a select - option list

```
<div class="social-option">
    <select name="hex_theme_options[social-service-1]">
        <option selected="selected" value="facebook">facebook</option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="twitter">twitter</option>
        <option value="linkedin">linkedin</option>
        <option value="e-mail">e-mail</option>
        <option value="phone">phone</option>
        <option value="instagram">instagram</option>
        <option value="flickr">flickr</option>
        <option value="dribbble">dribbble</option>
        <option value="skype">skype</option>
        <option value="picasa">picasa</option>
        <option value="google-plus">google-plus</option>
        <option value="forrst">forrst</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

why does this works on a PC but not on mac?

```
$('.social-option select').on('click', function () {
    alert('bla');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4BBcZ/

**UPDATE**
I need to use **on click** event, not **on change**.

Comment: check this (link)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900989/why-is-ff-on-os-x-losing-jquery-ui-in-click-event-handler]

Comment: hi thanks for the upvote but i think @JamWaffles deserves it more for expanation

Comment: This is a bug in chromium. Check this issue [Click event not fired for menulist <select> elements on Mac](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36518#c18)

Comment: 8 years ago, yet it's a common mistake xD

Answer (score 8):

Use the `change` event instead:

```
$('.social-option select').on('change', function () {
    alert('bla');
});
```

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

IIRC, the `click` event works for `<option>`s in Firefox, however does not work in Chrome. The best, most supported event is `change`.

To get the value of the option selected, simply use `.val()` as you would with any other input:

```
$('.social-option select').on('change', function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: yes that should answer the why in the question :)

Comment: thanks, this fixed an issue I had with select-boxes listening to click event. switching to the change event fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the "click" event, use "change", as in

```
 $(".social-option select").change(function(){
       alert('bla');    
    });
```

[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295642/jquery-function-doesnt-work-on-chrome-on-mac-but-works-on-chrome-on-win-7-and)