# Click event on select doesn't work on macs

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I have a `<select>` that would like to respond to a `click` event (using javascript).
On MacOS Chrome, no event is fired on click. This is a known problem (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384389/why-does-select-box-on-mac-chrome-doesnt-respond-to-click-event), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295642/jquery-function-doesnt-work-on-chrome-on-mac-but-works-on-chrome-on-win-7-and), …)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DvW5V/4/)

```
<select id='hodor'>
    <option>Jon Snow</option>
    <option>Joffrey</option>
</select>
```

and

```
$('#hodor').on('click change', function (e) {
    $(this).after("<li>"+e.type+"</li>");
});
```

**I already know that I can use the `change` event** (which I already do use). However the behavior is different for the end user and *I need to make it work accurately*: as soon as my select is clicked, I would like my UI to do something — not only when the selected option is changed.

What are my alternatives?

Kindly note: this is *not* a duplicate of other questions which allow for a "use the `change` event" answers. That's not what I am asking.

Comment: Is it just click or does the mouseup event have the same issue?

Comment: mouseup is broken too, mousedown works even though it's slightly different.

Comment: I've also tried to wrap it in a `div` or `span` but the select eats all the `click` and `mouseup` events...

Answer (score -1):

Use the `mousedown` event:

```
$('#hodor').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    $(this).after("<li>"+e.type+" " + $("option:selected", this).val() + "</li>");
});
```

Note that this fires before the user can select another option in the menu -- `.val()` returns the current value. I tried using `mouseup`, but that didn't fire.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h3AVw/7/)

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think your answer is incomplete: how do I use the mousedown event to emulate the click event?

Comment: It's not the same though... the event is fired differently.

Comment: It's the closest I could come up with. It fires when you click on the menu, not when you let go.